# tevilas kitchen carts

Tags: halacha, tevilas-keilim-dipping

Do stainless steel top kitchen carts require *tevila* prior to placing food items (such as fruit) directly on them?
[image: kitchen cart with apples]

Comment: how is this different than the question of the glass table?

Comment: @Ploni As suggested by msh210 on a related question, a table is often kept in the same place - so perhaps that's a specific ground for leniency. Alternatively, perhaps the cart is worse since glass is only miderabanan.

Comment: @Ploni Additionally, as per the picture, the cart looks like it may even be used for cutting fruit, making it an even bigger issue.

Comment: iIs a table ever considered a כלי  though?

Answer (score 1):

This כלי is not a כלי סעודה and therefor doesn't require tevilah (שו׳׳ע יו׳׳ד סי׳ ק׳׳כ), unless you eat off of it or prepare the food on it. This כלי isn't considered a storage vessel, being it only brings food back and forth. A regular storage vessel (like a sugar container next to your coffee machine) would normally require tevilah with out a bracha.

Comment: I'm not sure your definitions aren't a bit too narrow.  It seems there is a *machloketh haposkim* regarding refrigerator shelves. And the Shulchan Aruch rules you need tevila for a grill rack: http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.120.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en Neither case seem to qualify by your definitions.

Comment: I also suspect that people frequently snack off of kitchen carts, prepare food on them (the illustrative photo shows apples and a knife, suggesting a dual use as a cutting surface), and store food items, such as fruit, for days.

Comment: @Loewian if food is prepared on the cart then it wood need tevila maybe even with a bracha. Refrigerator shelves if the food is stored directly on it (not in a bag or container) would be considered a storage vessel, the machloketh haposkim is about whether the shelf are considered part of the fridge which is attached to the ground, or not part of the fridge because it can be removed. A grill rack needs tevila because you cook on it.